# Calling Python Script from Visual Studio C++ Solution

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I have an API in C++, which I got working with a sample Script. 
(Essentially it is giving me longitudinal signal output)
I want to use the output and write an analysis in a Python Script.
How do I call the Python Script from within this C++ solution within Visual Studio? How do I pass variables(data) to this python script by a call within Visual Studio in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

Comment: Nope, this question is related to using Python and C++ in Visual Studio including usage of debugger

Comment: well if you can't find the answer from that linked page (which I highly doubt) then I can't help you.

Comment: Well it seemed, I haven't set up Visual Studio correctly, this Video was telling me quite nicely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9RlT06a1EI
Sadly I found out, that this does not mean I can just write Python Code as I am used to

Answer (score 0):

I had to correctly set up the Visual Studio environement by : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9RlT06a1EI 
and then I had to write "Python"-Code in special format(also to be seen in Video)